# app signed on sierra crashed on el capitan

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan, macos-sierra, codesign

I have an application built with Xcode , all third party frameworks and dylib-s are code signed separtly , Application works fine on os x sierra ( tested in different devices) but crashed on os x El Capitan with

> Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)

( and again tested on several devices). 
here is the stack trace on crash on El Capitan

> Process:               BeSafe [671] Path:
>   /Applications/BeSafe.app/Contents/MacOS/BeSafe Identifier:
>   com.onecryptor.besafe Version:               0.2.6.0 (0.2.6.0) Code
>   Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1]
>   Responsible:           BeSafe [671] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2017-05-22 14:12:38.209 +0400 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   48F622B8-8E74-B38C-B200-580A63C6EFA7
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 1400 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
>   Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x0000000107462000
>   Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> kernel messages:
>   -0 sec            CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x107462000): p=671[BeSafe] final status 0x3004200, denying page sending SIGKILL
>   -0 sec            CODE SIGNING: process 671[BeSafe]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x107462000 from offset 0x0 in file
>   "/Applications/BeSafe.app/Contents/Frameworks/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib"
>   (cs_mtime:1495447699.0 == mtime:1495447699.0) (signed:1 validated:1
>   tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)
>
> VM Regions Near 0x107462000:
>       __LINKEDIT             00000001073b3000-0000000107462000 [  700K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/BeSafe.app/Contents/MacOS/BeSafe
>   --> mapped file            0000000107462000-0000000107463000 [    4K] r-x/r-x SM=PRV  1
>       VM_ALLOCATE            0000000107463000-0000000107464000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=ALI
>
> Application Specific Information: dyld: launch, loading dependent
>   libraries @executable_path/../Frameworks/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib
>
> Thread 0 Crashed: 0   dyld
>     0x00007fff66b70a10 memcmp + 208 1   dyld
>     0x00007fff66b5d905
>   ImageLoaderMachO::validateFirstPages(linkedit_data_command const*,
>   int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, long long,
>   ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 145 2   dyld
>     0x00007fff66b62b7b
>   ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int,
>   unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long
>   long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command
>   const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext
>   const&) + 283 3   dyld                            0x00007fff66b5ca6f
>   ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char
>   const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&,
>   ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 299 4   dyld
>     0x00007fff66b4f8c3 dyld::loadPhase6(int, stat const&, char const*,
>   dyld::LoadContext const&) + 402 5   dyld
>     0x00007fff66b54469 dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*,
>   dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector >*) + 710 6   dyld
>
>     0x00007fff66b54189 dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, char const*,
>   dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector >*) + 180 7   dyld
>
>     0x00007fff66b53c9f dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*,
>   dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector >*) + 1019 8   dyld
>
>     0x00007fff66b53643 dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*,
>   dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector >*) + 135 9   dyld
>
>     0x00007fff66b4f47b dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*,
>   dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector >*) + 213 10  dyld
>
>     0x00007fff66b4f15f dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&)
>   + 180 11  dyld                            0x00007fff66b54706 dyld::libraryLocator(char const*, bool, char const*,
>   ImageLoader::RPathChain const*) + 52 12  dyld
>     0x00007fff66b5a85e
>   ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&,
>   bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 384 13  dyld
>     0x00007fff66b5a564 ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&,
>   bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 80 14  dyld
>     0x00007fff66b50a12 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool,
>   ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 149 15  dyld
>     0x00007fff66b51b97 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long,
>   int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 3083
>   16  dyld                              0x00007fff66b4d276
>   dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long,
>   macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 512 17  dyld
>     0x00007fff66b4d036 _dyld_start + 54
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
>   0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000107462000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000 
>   rdx: 0x0000000000000768   rdi: 0x0000000107462000  rsi:
>   0x00007fff58bb6ad0  rbp: 0x00007fff58bb5d90  rsp: 0x00007fff58bb5d90
>   r8: 0x0000000000000003   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10:
>   0x0000000000000001  r11: 0x0000000000000202   r12: 0x0000000000000000 
>   r13: 0x0000000000000003  r14: 0x0000000000000768  r15:
>   0x00007fff66b8cce8   rip: 0x00007fff66b70a10  rfl: 0x0000000000010246 
>   cr2: 0x0000000107462000    Logical CPU:     3 Error Code:
>   0x00000004 Trap Number:     14
>
> Binary Images:
>          0x107046000 -        0x107375ffb +com.onecryptor.besafe (0.2.6.0 - 0.2.6.0) <880A6212-7110-317E-B4FA-1CF533E79AE5>
>   /Applications/BeSafe.app/Contents/MacOS/BeSafe
>          0x107465000 -        0x1074a1ff7 +org.sparkle-project.Sparkle (1.14.0 - 1.14.0) <85A19559-55A6-3BA3-AC85-543D647D8F30>
>   /Applications/BeSafe.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
>       0x7fff66b4c000 -     0x7fff66b82f5f  dyld (360.14)  /usr/lib/dyld
>
> External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes
>   targeting this process:
>       task_for_pid: 0
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
>       task_for_pid: 0
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
>       task_for_pid: 683
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0
>
> VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=4696K
>   resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=4696K(100%) Writable
>   regions: Total=10.2M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%)
>   unallocated=10.2M(100%)
>
> ```
>                             VIRTUAL   REGION  REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced)
> ```
>
> ===========                     =======  =======  Process Corpse Info               2048K        2  STACK GUARD                       56.0M        2 
>   Stack                             8192K        2  VM_ALLOCATE
>   4K        2 
>   __DATA                             536K        6 
>   __LINKEDIT                         968K        4 
>   __TEXT                            3728K        4  mapped file                          4K        2  shared memory                        8K        3 
>   ===========                     =======  =======  TOTAL                             71.1M       18
>
> Model: iMac11,3, BootROM VirtualBox, 4 processors, 2.2 GHz, 2 GB, SMC
>   2.3f35 Graphics: Display, PCI, 3 MB Memory Module: Bank 0/DIMM 0, 2 GB, DRAM, 1600 MHz, innotek GmbH, - Network Service: Ethernet,
>   Ethernet, en0 Serial ATA Device: VBOX HARDDISK, 84.83 GB Serial ATA
>   Device: VBOX CD-ROM, 59.4 MB USB Device: USB Bus USB Device: USB
>   Tablet USB Device: USB Keyboard Thunderbolt Bus:

Comment: **all third party frameworks and dylib-s are code signed separtly** - with the same or different certificate that's used with signing the main app? Note that the problem comes from trying to load the library `libboost_date_time-mt.dylib`. You can check its certificate with `codesign -dvvv <path to lib>`

Comment: @TheDarkKnight tanks for your comment , its turn out that my issue is solved using this question. the libs and app are signed with same certificate.